# Identify an unknown electronic component

Tags: identification, components

What are these orange components and what are they used for?

[image]

Comment: More pictures would be helpful, from different angles. And a schematic.

Comment: Plus, what is the product.

Comment: I don't think they're capacitors, but that color orange epoxy is exactly same as the famous "orange drop" capacitors....   https://www.tubesandmore.com/products/capacitors-orange-drop-600v-polyester

Comment: Looks like some sort of EMI suppressor such as a ferrite bead. Hard to tell from that angle though.

Answer (score 8):

They appear to be EMI filters similar to [these](https://www.globalsources.com/product/emi-filter_1086498298f.htm). They are used to suppress electomagnetic interference (EMI). As far as I know the coating is to keep the bead from rattling around on the wire.

[image]

Image from linked page.